# Firefox is using KDE oxygen GTK on Unity

Tags: unity, firefox, kde, desktop-environments, cinnamon

I am using **Ubuntu 14.04 with multiple desktop environments** (unity, cinnamon and KDE). However, after I installed KDE, Firefox began to use oxygen GTK when I am using Unity or Cinnamon.

If a click with right button on Firefox, I get this:

[image: Menu when clicked with right button. Don't know why the menu has this transparency]

I realized that others windows in firefox has the same oxygen style, like "open file". Below another screenshot.

[image]

How can I use each environment without one interfering into another one? Is it possible?

Comment: May be a silly question but did you look in the themes section to see if its listed there ? If not just try clicking default and see what happens

Comment: I went to Appearance > Theme. It was checked "Ambience (default)". I changed to "Adwaita" (all windows style changed), than I went back to "ambience". I opened Firefox and the problem persist. In Cinnamon, the Firefox menu is also using GTK Oxygen style.

Comment: You could try purging it, this will remove ALL data and reinstall, so sync it and back it up first so you don't lose any important data, in a tertminal `sudo apt-get purge firefox && apt-get install firefox` worth a try, I am having a hard time find any information on this issue

Comment: I purged, deleted `.mozilla` directory in my home, installed again and the problem still persists. I also tried to install another cinnamon theme. Same problem. So,purged KDE and... The problem gone away.

Comment: OK but do you want to use kde still ? If you do reinstall it and you can just remove the oxygen-gtk part like this `sudo apt-get purge gtk-oxygen*` including the * I read this here if you interested http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2074288.html the last post, this MIGHT let you have both